# Tikz picture plot borders not displayed

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker

When I export a ggplot in R via tikzdevice and include it in a common \figure or \figure* environment (in order to add caption and label), the borders of the plots are often (randomly?) missing. I use Texmaker, in overleaf it seems to work properly. Hence, I guess it is somehow related to the compiling of the pdf?
I use Quick build: PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + view PDF

[image: pdf output of Texmaker]

Comment: Does `\rule{1.2\textwidth}{1pt}` get cropped as well?  Does putting the tikzpicture inside a `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}` change anything?

Comment: If you zoom in, are they still missing?

Comment: Okay, if I zoom in the borders appear - I guess they are just not thick enough to make sure they get a black pixel :D